# Covering a zero-measure set in $R^n$ with cubic boxes

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have a question with 2 parts which I managed to solve the first part and having trouble with the second:

Suppose you have zero-measure set $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ (by our definition it means that for every $\epsilon >0$ we have closed boxes cover $I = \{I_k|k\in \mathbb N\}$ for A such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}v(I_k)<\epsilon$)

In the first part I had to show that there exist an $I'=\{I'_k|k\in \mathbb N\}$ cover such that for every $k\in\mathbb N$ the length of every interval in $I'_k$ is rational and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}v(I'_k)<\epsilon$.  (this one I managed to solve)

In the second part I have to find a cover $I$ for $A$ with **cubic boxes** which also have it cubic boxes volume sum smaller than $\epsilon$. and we have a hint - "common denominator".

My draft:
I tried to take a a certain box $I_k$ and look at his intervals lengths as rational numbers $\frac{p^k_i}{q^k_i}$ and the common denominator of the intervals is $q^k_1...q^k_n$, then I know I can cut the box into cubes with lengths of $\frac{1}{q^k_1...q^k_n}$.
the problem is that because I have infinite boxes, I need to find a constant common denominator that will be good for all the boxes in $I$.   or it is fine to say that if I manage to deal with some $I_k\in I$ i'm done ?